# Can a queue.bind operation is allowed for an user with read permissions in rabbit

Tags: rabbitmq

1. created a vhost
2. Created a user and assigned him below permissions for each configure , read and write

```
user    configure   read     write

user1     ^$         .*        ^$
```

However the read permissions has to allow user to bind a queue to an exchange but its throwing an error.